# Getting HTTP Error 500 in Azure web app communication with API - How to fix?

Tags: c#, azure, .net-7.0

I'm using Azure, having one Webapp (c#) communicating to an API (c#). The deploying was done using the Visual studio, but when I'm trying to call the api using the webapp I got this error:

> HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error
> The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.
> Most likely causes:
> -IIS received the request; however, an internal error occurred during the processing of the request. The root cause of this error depends on which module handles the request and what was happening in the worker process when this error occurred.
> -IIS was not able to access the web.config file for the Web site or application. This can occur if the NTFS permissions are set incorrectly.
> IIS was not able to process configuration for the Web site or application.
> -The authenticated user does not have permission to use this DLL.
> -The request is mapped to a managed handler but the .NET Extensibility Feature is not installed

Thanks for your help

- I redployed many times
- Checked the webconfig
- The communication was OK, when I did a new publish it stopped
- .Net 7.0

Comment: The 500 error indicates the server made an error while processing the request.  It could be for millions of reasons.  Most likely your request was wrong since you are using a well tested Azure API.  Make sure you read the module documentation.  Error says it is a IIS error which indicates you are using an old server which may not support the API you are using.  Old IIS servers may not support newer encryption mode that are being used for the permissions.

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to uncheck (or implement) in the AZURE -> API APP -> APIs -> Settings and check the Subscription option

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add a VNet
In the portal menu choose Virtual networks
Select Create, choose your resource group

Then go to your webapi, choose Networking under Settings
Choose VNet integration in the Outbound Traffic box on the right and select the new VNet you created